# ARM Keil: DCB opcode not initialising memory from another AREA

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

Please find the below assembly program. The issue is that R3 and R4 is empty after LDRB instruction. Memory also does not initialise using DCB. Can anyone help with this program?
How can I initialise memory with the string and load it in register?

```
AREA RESET, CODE, READONLY
ENTRY

MOV R0,#length;
LDR R1,=str1;
LDR R2,=str2;

LDRB R3,[R1];
LDRB R4,[R2];

EOR R3,R3,R4;
EOR R4,R3,R4;
EOR R3,R3,R4;

STR R3,[R1];
STR R4,[R2];
STOP B STOP;
AREA RES, DATA, READWRITE
str1 DCB "kcz778unTS",0;

str2 DCB "cYUrk2hcIj",0;

length EQU 0xA;

END
```

Comment: Using three XOR instructions to swap to registers is a horrible hack used on x86 processors.  It should never be used on ARM.  It creates a false data dependency which will harm performance on faster cores, and it makes the code horrible to read!  In this case you don't even need to swap the registers, just change the operands of the following instructions.

Comment: Also, you don't have a function label, but if this is meant to be a function you can't use r4 until you have saved whatever was in it previously by pushing it to the stack and popping it before you return.